Linear functional on a Hilbert space defined by a sesquilinear form can be expressed in certain manner when restricting to a finite dim. subspace
Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $a : H \times H \to \mathbb{K}$ where $\mathbb{K}$ is either complex or real numbers, a sesquilinear form such that there exist constants $C, c  > 0$ such that
$$ |a(x,y) | \leq C ||x|| ||y|| ,  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ Re( a(x,x) ) \geq c ||x||^2$$
I want to show that, for a finite dimensional subspace $Y$ of $X$, and for each $x \in X$, there exists $y \in Y$ such that $a(z, x ) = a(z, y)$ for all z in $Y$. Since Y is finite dimensional it is closed in $X$ so there exists a linear map $P : X \rightarrow Y$ such that $(z, x - Px) = 0$ for all $z \in Y, x \in X$, but this has gotten me nowhere. I thought about restricting the operator $A$ given by $a(x,y ) = (x, Ay) $ by the Max-Milgram theorem to $Y$ and then taking the adjoint, but I would require that $A A^* Y \subseteq Y$ or a similar condition. Any help is appreciated.

Since $a(z,x)$ is a bounded sesquilinear form
there is a bounded linear operator $A$ such that
$$a(z,x)=\langle Az,x\rangle \quad z,x\in H$$
We have $$\|Ax\|\,\|x\|\ge |\langle Ax,x\rangle|= |a(x,x)|\ge |{\rm Re}\,a(x,x)|\ge c\|x\|^2$$
Thus $\|Ax\|\ge c\|x\|$ for $x\in H.$ Therefore the operator $A$ is injective and its range $A(H)$ is closed.
Fix $0\neq x\in H.$ Assume there is $y\in Y$ such that
$$\langle Az,x\rangle=\langle Az,y\rangle,\quad z,x\in Y$$
The latter is equivalent to $Az\perp x-y$ for any $z\in Y,$ i.e. $x-y\perp A(Y),$ or $x\in Y+A(Y)^\perp.$
So the conclusion holds iff $H=Y+A(Y)^\perp.$
Assume by contradiction that $Y+A(Y)^\perp \subsetneq H.$
Then there is $x$ such that $x\perp Y$ and $x\in \overline{A(Y)}=A(Y).$ Then $x=Ay$ for some $y$ and $Ay\perp Y.$ Hence $$0=|\langle y,Ay\rangle |=|a(y,y)|\ge c\|y\|^2>0$$ a contradicton.
Remark The proof does not require that $Y$ is finite dimensional. Moreover the assumption $|a(x,x)|\ge c\|x\|^2$ suffices.
